# AWS Translation Service Creating Incorrect Translation in using Real Time and API Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, translate

when I transcribe my video, it works fine by generating an accurate vtt file.

while using AWS translate service to translate the above-generated vtt to any other language,
translate captions are disturbing due to the followings:

1: on milliseconds, it puts an extra space.  (highlighted in rectangles)

2: converts --> sign to —> sign. (highlighted in ovals)

3: removes T from WEBVTT while translating to Urdu. It generates WEBVT instead of WEBVTT.

```
IAmazonTranslate translateClient = new AmazonTranslateClient(AWSAccessKey, AWSSecretKey, RegionEndpoint.EUWest1);
translateTextRequest = (new TranslateTextRequest()
                    {
                        Text = contentText,
                        SourceLanguageCode = "en",
                        TargetLanguageCode = targetLanguageCode   //fr, ur
                    });
TranslateTextResponse translateTextResponse = translateClient.TranslateText(translateTextRequest);
```

[image]

Comment: I wonder if it is due to the fact that the file is using UTF-8? It might also be a result of the text editor you are using. What program are you using to view the files (eg Visual Studio Code)? Converting `-->` into different characters is normally seen in Word Processors that try to improve the text, whereas Text Editors will never modify the content without you telling it to do so.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein; I am not using any external editor. I am translating my videos to different languages. in step#1, I transcribe my video to "english.vtt". In step#2, I read text of "english.vtt" from S3 bucket, In step#3, I convert text using AWS and save it to "french.vtt".  and it gives wrong timing duration.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein; I am facing this issue using real time translation service also.

Comment: What displayed the text in the images that you highlighted? Was it just `cat` on a text file, or was it opened in an editor?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein; nop it was'nt open in any editor. just using system.io for reading the content.

Comment: Sorry, but I am confused. What do you mean by "just using system.io"? How are you displaying the content of the files on your screen? Have you tried writing the translation to disk and then opening the file to inspect it that way? I suspect that your method of displaying the translation is causing the changes.